# NiceGui: Multiline Button

Tags: python, nicegui

How can I make a multiline button in nicegui?

[image]

Quasar example just uses a `<br>` tag, but it gets escaped by nicegui.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting plain html inside a the button as a workaround

```
    with ui.button():
        ui.html('hello<br>world')
```